# Find referring email from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, backlinks, traffic

Recently I've found a huge spike in web traffic in the Google Analytics "email" category.  I can guess at where this is from, but because it's not an actual website it's hard to see the source -- or whether this spike simply indicates that users are verifying their email addresses and triggering this event.  How can I see the email/email sender/URL data about the emails referring to my website?  I'm suspecting I've been mentioned in a newsletter and knowing which one would be hugely beneficial to growing my site.

[image: Graph of user acquisition]